# Win32com Excel: after copying a sheet to a summary file, the number of sheets changes

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to merge all xlsx files in a folder into a summary file, using win32com:

```
        for file in range(len(segments[segment])):
            w = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), segments[segment][file]), ReadOnly=1)
            w.Sheets(1).Copy(After=wb.Worksheets(file + 1))
            wb.ActiveSheet.Name = segments[segment][file]
            w.Close(SaveChanges=True)
```

And number of pages in copied file and summary file is different, despite completely identical print and sheet settings in both files. And it doesn’t depend on whether I use "ReadOnly=1" or not.
A sheet in a copied file:

[image]

And in a summary file:

[image]

Why are they different?